# Github compare two different repository from different users

Tags: git, github

I want to compare `repo_a` from `user_a` AND `repo_b` from `user_b`. I tried to fork them but I still can't compare them!

How can I do this? Can i do it with the Github website? I want to compare them visually, not just in a log file.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub can do a [comparing across forks](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparing-across-forks). For example, you can compare the forked repository's master with origin's master like:

```
https://github.com/octocat/linguist/compare/master...octo-org:master
```

See [GitHub Documentation: Comparing commits across time](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/)

Comment: @M.Khajavi How do you define _same_ repo? For me, `user-a:project` and `user-b:project` are different Git repositories.

Comment: https://github.com/user_a/repo_a/compare/master...user_b:master - where can i set repo_b?

Comment: You can't. The repository of user B can only be  `repo_a`, because it's a fork of user A's `repo_a`. It's not a common use-case to compare two completely different repos... If you really want to do this, I think you need to download both of them and do a `diff` locally.

Comment: @MohamadKh75 Use Meld for local comparision

Answer (score 1):

You could see the command-line tool [github-compare](https://github.com/anqiansong/github-compare)

```
github-compare urfave/cli spf13/cobra

┌─────────────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ METRICS                 │ URFAVE/CLI     │ SPF13/COBRA        │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│  homepage             │ <nil>          │ https://cobra.dev  │
│  language             │ Go             │ Go                 │
│  license              │ MIT License    │ Apache License 2.0 │
│ ⏰ age                  │ 3237 days      │ 3185 days          │
│  stars                │ 18354(5/d)     │ 26748(8/d)         │
│  latestDayStarCount   │ 8 (down)       │ 18 (up)            │
│  latestWeekStarCount  │ 99 (up)        │ 115 (up)           │
│  latestMonthStarCount │ 396            │ 499                │
│  forks                │ 1564(0/d)      │ 2325(0/d)          │
│  watchers             │ 304            │ 350                │
│  issues               │ 134/650        │ 107/891            │
│  pull requests        │ 22/751         │ 55/808             │
│  contributors         │ 244            │ 246                │
│  releases             │ 46             │ 16                 │
│  release circle(avg)  │ 70 days        │ 199 days           │
│  lastRelease          │ 1 day(s) ago   │ 2 month(s) ago     │
│  lastCommit           │ 17 hour(s) ago │ 23 hour(s) ago     │
│  lastUpdate           │ 2 hour(s) ago  │ 1 hour(s) ago      │
└─────────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```